# rspec: Helpers Method on Model undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm getting an issue with helpers method included in my model.

I include my helpers as follow:

```rb
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  include BookingsHelper
  include PaymentsHelper
```

Both of `BookingsHelper` and `PaymentsHelper` have `slack_notify` function. 
So in order to call the good `slack_notify` function I call this function as below:

```
BookingsHelper.slack_notify(self)
PaymentsHelper.slack_notify(requester.email, 'danger', 'booking:proceed_payment', e.message)
```

When I run my test (with rspec) I got:

```
     Failure/Error: BookingsHelper.slack_notify(self)

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `slack_notify' for BookingsHelper:Module
```

And I noticed if I change: `BookingsHelper.slack_notify(self)` by `slack_notify(self)` it works but call the `slack_notify` in `PaymentsHelper` so I don't really understand what's happening. And if I remove the `PaymentHelper` it call the good one

If someone could highlight me on this behavior, I would be really interested to understand whats going on

Thanks

Comment: You're assuming that Ruby generates static versions of each of the module functions - this is not the case.

Comment: @maxpleaner thanks for your answer but i'm sure to get exactly what you mean

Comment: The use of the term "helper" here is inappropriate. In Rails helpers are modules that are used in the controller and view layer but almost never in the model layer. A module used to DRY models is called a `concern` and is usually named after what features it actually brings to the table like for example `Commentable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Mixin here.

> A mixin can basically be thought of as a set of code that can be added
>   to one or more classes to add additional capabilities without using
>   inheritance. In Ruby, a mixin is code wrapped up in a module that a
>   class can include or extend

You do not access helper methods like the static methods but you call them directly, in your example you should call `slack_notify` directly without having module name before.
When you include two modules which have the same method name then the last one overrides the previous one.
If you do not want it to be overriden then you have to define in the module like that:

```
def BookingsHelper.slack_notify
  // your code
end
```

and

```
def PaymentsHelper.slack_notify
  // your code
end
```

see the example about `sin` and `cos` here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm

Read more about mixins and you will have better understanding of what is going on here.

Comment: The term "static methods" is not really a good fit for Ruby. Ruby has class and module methods and the only real difference between them and "regular" instance methods is that they are attached to a instance of the Class or Module class. It does not have a `static` keyword like Java or PHP.